# What wysiwyg editors can be load with ajax?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, wysiwyg

Working on a blog application in C# with MVC and want to load a wysiwyg editor with ajax on a page.
only not all editors works good to load with ajax.

What editor works to load with ajax ?

and what are your experiences doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Editor

This editor can be initialised at any time. 
Its also very popular.

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

I use it on my CMS so I know that it works.

Answer (score 1):

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) is a popular feature-rich open source editor that I in Ajax applications. Check out this [example using jQuery](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery) to populate the editor using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

We did it with TinyMce editor, previously have essential editor scripts loaded in main page.. Not very elegant solution, but viable.
Also you can use [jWYSIWYG](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/) editor for that, it's very lightweight